# Google Maps batch reverse Geocoding Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps

So I know that Google API v3 prevents batch requests unless there is a 2 second delay - So I'm just trying to do a simple reverse Geocode using one request.

You can see my array now only has one object (for now).

The problem is that I'm returning an "undefined" value under the function "showAddress()". What's weird is that the address shows just fine on the google maps marker - but it won't let me return the value properly.

Please ignore the fact I'm using extra functions when I don't need to - I will need these functions later for my full setup.

Here's a JSBin --> http://jsbin.com/japudabu/1/edit?html,output

I think the problem is more here:

```
....

  infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  return results[0].formatted_address;

...
```

Here's the full setup:

Javascript:

```
var geoArray = [
    {lat: 29.546604, lng: -98.407082}/*,
    {lat: 29.402672, lng: -98.392095},
    {lat: 29.769542, lng: -98.664527},
    {lat: 29.778432, lng: -98.464939},
    {lat: 29.78322, lng: -98.523551},
    {lat: 29.424455, lng: -98.403565},
    {lat: 29.342814, lng: -98.541336},
    {lat: 29.291922, lng: -98.434656},
    {lat: 29.354486, lng: -98.400621},
    {lat: 29.512927, lng: -98.439247},
    {lat: 29.386556, lng: -98.510591},
    {lat: 29.365009, lng: -98.427818},
    {lat: 29.363518, lng: -98.583277},
    {lat: 29.305123, lng: -98.429247},
    {lat: 29.673901, lng: -98.39694},
    {lat: 29.530874, lng: -98.446433}
    {lat: 29.374788, lng: -98.602789} */];

 var geocoder;
  var map;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var marker;
    function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(29.4814305,-98.5144044);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 11,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    }
   // alert(mapOptions);
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
  }




  function codeLatLng(lat, lng) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
          map.setZoom(11);
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: latlng,
              map: map
          });
          infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          return results[0].formatted_address;
        } else {
          alert('No results found');
        }
      } else {
        alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

  function showAddress() {
    for (var i = 0; i < geoArray.length; i++) {
        var x = 29.546604;
        var y = -98.407082;
        var myval = "address is: " + codeLatLng(x,y) + "<br/>";
        var thediv = document.getElementById('listme');
        thediv.innerHTML = thediv.innerHTML + myval;
    }

  }
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API v3 Example: Reverse Geocoding</title>
<link href="https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
<body onload='initialize();'>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="Reverse Geocode" onclick="showAddress()">
  </div>
   <div id="map_canvas" style="height: 80%; width:50%; border: 1px solid black;"></div>
   <div id='listme' style='position:fixed;bottom:10;left:10;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your posted code doesn't use the geocoder at all.

Comment: Posting the url to the Google APIs is unnecessary - Look at the JSBin.

Comment: @geocodezip I'm still confused at your comment. I am clearly using the geocoder - How else would the demo (see JSBin) pull an address? Did you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry, it was hiding, didn't see it.

Comment: All code is posted. I highly recommend you look at the JSbin as it clearly demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @geocodezip his jsBin is perfectly valid. I recommend you read question properly downvoting someone.. Look at the answer below which I modified from his JSBin.. which does use geocoding...

Comment: What is the problem?  The posted code works for me.

Comment: oh and @bagofmilk +1 to counter the unjust -1 you got..

Comment: @geocodezip at the bottom, his address is printed as 'undefined'..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There I fixed it for you:

http://jsbin.com/japudabu/4/

Your problem was that codeLatLng(lat, lng) does some asynchronous processing. So you cannot just say return from within that process. That's why your function always returned undefined.

The right way to do it is add a call back to the `codeLatLng(lat, lng)` like this:

```
function codeLatLng(lat, lng, callback) {  ///<<-------CHANGE HERE
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[1]) {
              map.setZoom(11);
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  position: latlng,
                  map: map
              });
              infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
              callback(results[0].formatted_address);   ///<<-------CHANGE HERE
              //return results[0].formatted_address;   ///<<------- CAN'T DO THIS..
            } else {
              alert('No results found');
            }
          } else {
            alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
```

and once google finds the address fire your call back. You will have to modify your showAddress() like this:

```
function showAddress() {
        for (var i = 0; i < geoArray.length; i++) {
            var x = 29.546604;
            var y = -98.407082;
            codeLatLng(x,y,function(address){   ///<<-------CHANGE HERE
              var myval = "address is: " + address + "<br/>";
              var thediv = document.getElementById('listme');
              thediv.innerHTML = thediv.innerHTML + myval;
            });
        }

      }
```

Notice how I am passing a function to `codeLatLng`. Hope that helps you understand. Please ask if you dont. Check the new JS Bin i have posted above to see it running.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! Do you know where I can find more information on the "callback" command?

Comment: callback is not a command.. its just code and how JavaScript works. You can pass function as a parameter to another function and have it execute when ever you want.. you can rename that 'callback' to 'elephants' if you want.. and change the call to elephants(results[0].formatted_address) and it will still work.. Here is a good link to read more about it: http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/